# Unique value combinations with summary count

Tags: r, plyr, summary

Say I have the following data

```
x <- (c(1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2))
y <- (c(3,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,3))
table <- data.frame(x,y)
```

How would one calculate the frequencies of a unique combinations, ie 1-4

I have looked into `summary((table$x)[1] & (table$y)[2])`

Does it involve using the the `unique` and `length` commands?
Or must I use the `plyr` package and then use `ddply`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you looking for `table(x, y)`? (It's also not a great idea to name a `data.frame` object `table`; `table` is a pretty commonly used function in R. Nothing would break really, but it's just confusing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ananda suggets the function `table` is likely the way to go:

```
> df <- data.frame(x, y)
> table(df)
   y
x   3 4
  1 2 4
  2 3 2
> table(with(df, paste(x, y, sep="-")))

1-3 1-4 2-3 2-4 
  2   4   3   2
```